# Further queries on inside-out polygonal dissections

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, computational-geometry

The following is based on [Inside-out polygonal dissections](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186332/inside-out-polygonal-dissections?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Definition:** We say that a polygon P has an inside-out dissection into another polygon P'  if P′ is congruent to P, and the perimeter of P becomes interior to P′, and so the perimeter of P′ is composed of internal cuts of the dissection of P.

**Question:** What if we further insist that no point on the boundary of P should be on the boundary of P'? In the example inside-out dissections shown in above linked discussion, there are isolated points of the boundary of the input polygon P that are also on the boundary of P'.

Note 1: The Existence of such *'totally inside out'* dissections is not hard to show for any triangle and hence for any polygon. But the *least number of intermediate pieces* even for a "triangle to congruent triangle" dissection seems considerably more than 4 (the number conjectured on above-linked page) - especially if we insist that all intermediate pieces need to be simple and convex polygons (as is indeed the case in the dissections shown in the above-linked page). A simple-minded method can turn a triangle totally inside out via 7 intermediate pieces out of which 6 are convex and 1 piece will have 3 holes - and this piece will have to be cut into several convex pieces.

Note 2: The inside-out and totally inside-out dissections appear to have interesting analogs in 3D - the simplest example is that a cube can be turned inside out (but *not* totally inside out) via 8 smaller cubes.

**Further question:** If we add this *totally inside-out* condition to general dissections where P and P' are only equal area planar regions (not congruent), will it impact classical results such as the Wallace-Bolyai-Gerwein theorem, Tarski circle-squaring etc..?