# Inside-out dissections of polygons - a generalization

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry, computational-geometry

**Definitions** ([Inside-out polygonal dissections](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186332/inside-out-polygonal-dissections)):  a polygon P  has an *inside out dissection* into P' if  P′ is congruent to P and the perimeter of P becomes interior to P' and so the perimeter of P' is composed of internal cuts in the dissection of P. The dissection to P' is *totally inside out* ([Further queries on inside-out polygonal dissections](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/394823/further-queries-on-inside-out-polygonal-dissections)) if we further insist that no point on the boundary of P is on the boundary of P'. These definitions have natural analogs in 3D.

Let us drop the requirement that the final polygon (or solid) P' be congruent to P but only insist on the inside-out (or totally inside out) nature of the dissection of P into P'.

**Question 1:** Given a convex polygonal region, will it always have an inside out dissection into *some* convex polygonal region? If the answer is "yes" (as seems to be the case), is there some algorithm by which one achieve such a dissection for an n-gon with least number of intermediate pieces (we don't insist that these pieces are convex but are simple polygons)? If the answer is "no", how does one decide whether a given polygonal region has such a dissection?

**Question 2:** same question as 1 with the 'fully inside out' requirement.

**Note added on 21st March, 2023:** Following comment below and with reference to the Wallace Bolyai Gerwein theorem, one could guess that any polygon P can be inside-out dissected (or even fully inside out dissected) into any other polygon P' with the same area. So the existence part of both above questions seems to have a "yes" answer. What remains is given a P to find that P' into which it can be transformed via the least number of intermediate pieces.

Note: Some further thoughts are recorded at http://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2023/03/inside-out-dissections-contd.html

Comment: Isn't the answer to the 1st question in **Q1** *Yes* because the original cited question showed that there is an inside-out dissection to a congruent $P'$? So loosening to a noncongruent $P'$ leaves the answer *Yes*?

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing this out. Indeed, one could triangulate P in such a way that each triangle has two of the edges of P and then inside-out each of these triangles - via 4 pieces each (as given in your original post). That easily gives an inside-out dissection of P. So the only issue with allowing P' to be any shape (probably) is whether P can be inside-outed  into some shape other than itself via less intermediate pieces than into P itself.

Comment: Taking things a little bit further, even for question 2 (totally inside out) the  possibility answer appears to be "yes".  With both questions, *Specifying a specific P' could be of interest - whether one can inside out a general n-gon into a square, say*.