# Inside-out dissections of solids

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, polyhedra

We add to [Inside-out dissections of polygons - a generalization](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442965/inside-out-dissections-of-polygons-a-generalization). The inside-out (fully inside-out) dissections are defined on pages linked there.

1. How does one inside-out dissect a tetrahedron into some polyhedron of same volume, not necessarily a tetrahedron, using the least number of intermediate pieces that are themselves polyhedrons?
2. Same question as 1 with inside-out replaced by 'fully inside-out'.

Guess: If a polyhedron P can be dissected into another polyhedron P' with same volume (the possibility is captured by Dehn invariant), then there are both inside-out and fully inside-out dissections of P to P'.