# Inside-out dissection

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

In a recent problem in The College Math Journal (1230) a Heronian triangle is called to have an **equivalent rectangle** if there exists an integer sided rectangle with the same area and perimeter. For example $a=68$, $b=87$, $c=95$ and sides of the rectangle $x=30$ and $y=95$. Can one find an inside-out dissection of one to the other (as defined in [Inside-out polygonal dissections](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/186332/inside-out-polygonal-dissections)) that will show that the conditions are met in a graphical way? I guess the last requirement is a little harder to describe (like those proofs without words that can be decoded after staring at the picture for a while).

Comment: How would such an inside-out dissection confirm the conditions? Perhaps you need a dissection which preserves  the property 'segment is on the boundary'?